# React Hooks, React-Router, and Userbase

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-hooks

I'm working on a React website and learning about React Hooks. In the project below, `header.tsx` and `home.tsx` are both components inside `App.tsx`. I have a `user` state object; i.e. `const [user, setUser] = useState<UserResult>();` that I load in all 3 files (is this wrong?).

When I log into [userbase](https://userbase.com/docs/sdk/) in `home.tsx`, the UI reflects the change - the conditional body in `home.tsx` reflects the fact that `user` went from undefined to defined and the log out button is shown.

Here's the problem: I want `header.tsx` to also reflect the change in `user`; i.e. I expect `header.tsx` to be "listening" for changes in `user` and reflecting them on the UI, but it doesn't happen.

Can anyone shed any light? I'm also unsure of the placement of the `userbase.init()` call.

For some background, this project is based off [this tutorial](https://dev.to/danbockapps/how-to-use-userbase-in-a-react-web-app-with-typescript-gh). I modified it to add React Router.

`App.tsx`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/header';
import Home from './components/home';
import userbase, {UserResult} from 'userbase-js';

function App() {
  const [user,setUser] = useState<UserResult>();
  useEffect(() => {
    userbase.init({ appId: process.env.REACT_APP_USERBASE_APP_ID as string })
        .then(session => session.user && setUser(session.user))
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`home.tsx`

```
import React, { ChangeEvent, FormEvent, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import userbase, { UserResult } from 'userbase-js';

function Home() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<UserResult>();

    const [regForm, setRegForm] = useState<{
        username?: string,
        password?: string
        }>({ username: '', password: '' });
    const handleRegInputChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
        setRegForm({ ...regForm, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    
    const handleRegSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (regForm.username && regForm.password) {
            userbase.signUp({
            username: regForm.username,
            password: regForm.password,
            rememberMe: 'session'
            }).then((ur: UserResult) => setUser(ur))
            .catch(err => alert(err));
        }
    }

    const [loginForm, setLoginForm] = useState<{
        username?: string,
        password?: string
    }>({ username: '', password: '' });

    const handleLoginInputChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => 
        setLoginForm({ ...loginForm, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });

    const handleLoginSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (loginForm.username && loginForm.password) {
            userbase.signIn({
                username: loginForm.username,
                password: loginForm.password,
                rememberMe: 'session'
            }).then((ur: UserResult) => setUser(ur))
              .catch(err => alert(err));
        }
    }

    const handleLogout = () => {
        userbase.signOut().then(() => setUser(undefined))
            .catch(err => alert(err));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Homepage</h2>
            <a href="/robertbrennan">Show example profile</a>
            <br/>

            {user ? (
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Signed in as {user.username}.{' '}
                        <button onClick={handleLogout}>Log out</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    <h3>Register</h3>
                        <form onSubmit={handleRegSubmit}>
                            <label>
                                Username:
                                <input type="text" name="username" value={regForm?.username} onChange={handleRegInputChange} />
                            </label>

                            <label>
                                Password:
                                <input type="password" name="password" value={regForm?.password} onChange={handleRegInputChange} />
                            </label>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </form>

                        <br/><br/><hr/><br/>

                        <h3>Log in</h3>
                        <form onSubmit={handleLoginSubmit}>
                            <label>
                                Username:
                                <input type="text" name="username"
                                value={loginForm?.username} onChange={handleLoginInputChange} />
                            </label>

                            <label>
                                Password:
                                <input type="password" name="password"
                                    value={loginForm?.password} onChange={handleLoginInputChange} />
                            </label>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                )}            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

`header.tsx`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { UserResult } from 'userbase-js';

function Header(props: any) {
    const [user] = useState<UserResult>();

    return (
        <div>
            <h1><a href="/">Project</a></h1>
            Username: {user?.username}     <---- THIS DOESN'T CHANGE!
            <hr/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you notice that you created 2 useState for the user, one in App.tsx another in header.tsx. That is the main problem. If you want to share the user, passing the user from App to header as props, instead of creating another one.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

`App.tsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, ChangeEvent, FormEvent } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/header';
import Home from './components/home';
import Register from './components/register';
import Login from './components/login';
import userbase, { UserResult } from 'userbase-js';

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserResult>();
  const [toHome, setToHome] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    userbase.init({ appId: process.env.REACT_APP_USERBASE_APP_ID as string })
        .then(session => session.user && setUser(session.user))
  }, []);

  const [regForm, setRegForm] = useState<{
    username?: string,
    password?: string
    }>({ username: '', password: '' });
  const handleRegInputChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
      setRegForm({ ...regForm, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });

  const handleRegSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (regForm.username && regForm.password) {
          userbase.signUp({
          username: regForm.username,
          password: regForm.password,
          rememberMe: 'session'
        }).then((ur: UserResult) => {
            setUser(ur)
            setToHome(true);
          }).catch(err => alert(err));
      }
  }

  const [loginForm, setLoginForm] = useState<{
      username?: string,
      password?: string
  }>({ username: '', password: '' });

  const handleLoginInputChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => 
      setLoginForm({ ...loginForm, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });

  const handleLoginSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (loginForm.username && loginForm.password) {
          userbase.signIn({
              username: loginForm.username,
              password: loginForm.password,
              rememberMe: 'session'
          }).then((ur: UserResult) => {
            setUser(ur);
            setToHome(true);
          }).catch(err => alert(err));
      }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header user={user}/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/'>
          <Home user={user} setUser={setUser} />
        </Route>

        <Route exact path='/register'>
          <Register 
            handleRegSubmit={handleRegSubmit}
            regForm={regForm}
            handleRegInputChange={handleRegInputChange}
            toHome={toHome}
          />
        </Route>

        <Route exact path="/login">
          <Login 
            handleLoginSubmit={handleLoginSubmit}
            loginForm={loginForm}
            handleLoginInputChange={handleLoginInputChange}
            toHome={toHome}
          />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`Header.tsx`:

```
function Header(props: any) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1><a href="/">Project</a></h1>

            {props.user ? (
                <div>
                    Username: {props.user?.username}
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    Not logged in
                </div>
            )}
            
            <hr/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

`Register.tsx`: (`Login.tsx` is very similar)

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

function Register(props: any) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.toHome ? <Redirect to="/" /> : null}

            <h3>Register</h3>
            <form onSubmit={props.handleRegSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Username:
                    <input type="text" name="username" value={props.regForm?.username} onChange={props.handleRegInputChange} />
                </label>

                <label>
                    Password:
                    <input type="password" name="password" value={props.regForm?.password} onChange={props.handleRegInputChange} />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Register;
```